# Model useragreement in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a user agreement that the users needs to accept. From time to time, the agreement changes so the users will need to accept again.

I want to store this in mongo so that the effort of checking if the user has agreed to the latest terms and showing that terms is as efficient as possible.

So the naive implementation would be to have one document containing the agreement, the time that agreement was created, and an array of users that has agreed.

Then I could ask for the last doc sorted by date, and projected a new property to it telling whether the user was present in the array or not.

It would also be quite simple to add the user to that array when the user agrees to the terms.

The problem with this approach is the growing array of users in the array.

I've seen strategies for 'fanning out on write' to solve the array-size challenge, but do not understand fully how I would go about queried for the latest agreement AND the info about current user agreeing or not in one call..

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can store the latestAgreementAccepted id in the user document instead of maintaining an array of users in the agreement document. The trade off would be to update each user's latestAgreementAccepted id field.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about this. 
There is only one problem: I don't have a user document...
Of cause, I can create one, but this will result in two queries to check if the user has agreed: One for the latest agreement, and one for the user check. I would rather have this in one query if it's possible..